# Prevent pip from caching a package

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, python-wheel

Is there a way to tell pip never to create a wheel cache of my package?

## Background

I wrote a package for in-house use that sets up some symbolic links when installed using `cmdclass` in the `setup.py`.  These post-install and post-develop triggers run fine if I install the sdist, but if I compile the package to a wheel, they do not run.  To counter this, I make sure to only upload the sdist to our internal PyPI.

## Problem

[According to the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#wheel-cache), when pip installs from an sdist it compiles it to a wheel and caches it for next time.  This means that the package installs right the first time, but subsequent installs are broken.

I know I could run pip with `--no-cache-dir`, but I want to be sure everyone on my team can get the package correctly without having to add flags like this.  There is no situation where someone would want a wheel of this package.

## Question

Is there a setting or config variable I can set in my package to tell pip never to cache it as a wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *clean* way of doing this that I know of. You can take your chances and play *dirty*.

Inspired by this [comment](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-517-and-projects-that-cant-install-via-wheels/791/6), you could try with a `setup.py` script that looks like this (only partially tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='LookMaNoWheels',
    version='1.2.3',
    cmdclass={'bdist_wheel': None},
)
```

The idea is to force a failure when trying to build a wheel. When this happens, tools such as *pip* tend to recover from this by installing directly from whatever distribution is available instead (in your case a *sdist*).

---

**Update**

Something like this would help provide a more informative error message:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import distutils.errors
import setuptools

bdist_wheel = None

try:
    import wheel.bdist_wheel
    class bdist_wheel(wheel.bdist_wheel.bdist_wheel):
        def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
            raise distutils.errors.DistutilsClassError("No!")
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    pass

setuptools.setup(
    name='LookMaNoWheels',
    version='1.2.3',
    cmdclass={'bdist_wheel': bdist_wheel},
)
```

Comment: I like your dirty tactics and package naming scheme!  I get a big `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`, but the sdist installs and the wheel isn't cached

Comment: There is probably a nice way to deliver a more informative message in order to avoid scaring the users of your package.