# run post_install on pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

In my classic `setup.py` script, I have a post_install method that registers my python widget with a jupyter notebook.  How do I do this using the pyproject.toml file?  I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

doc: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/extension.html

I have these classes defined in my `setup.py` file that need to be run.  Is there a way to replicate this in the new pyproject.toml system?

```
# Each of these classes represent the different modes that pip install
# can go into, and what logic can be run after pip install finishes
class develop(_develop):
    """Post-installation logic to run for development mode"""

    def run(self):
        self.execute(_post_install, (), msg="Running post-install...")
        super().run()


class install(_install):
    """Post-installation logic to run for installation mode"""

    def run(self):
        self.execute(_post_install, (), msg="Running post-install...")
        super().run()


class egg_info(_egg_info):
    """Post-installation logic to run for 'egg_info' mode"""

    def run(self):
        self.execute(_post_install, (), msg="Running post-install...")
        super().run()
```

In the setup.py here is the part that I need to call:

```
 "cmdclass": {
        "develop": develop,
        "install": install,
        "egg_info": egg_info,
    },
```

Comment: Not possible. When using current versions of *pip* and *wheels* and all the modern packaging tools there is no concept of "post install" step. -- Maybe we can still help you get to your actual goal which seems to be to register some widgets into a Jupyter notebook, if you create a new question with this framing.

Comment: I modified with what I am trying to replicate.

Comment: Not possible. *pip* (and any other modern installer) always installs from a *wheel*. If there is no *wheel* available, *pip* builds a *wheel* from the *sdist*. And *wheels* do not contain any `setup.py`, at all.

Comment: what if I don't want to use a wheel?  I would prefer an sdist. wheels are a pain to manage.

Comment: I do not think you have a choice. This is the process. You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58290113), but I do not know if it still works, and I really would not recommend it. -- You still have not clearly explained why you want to do a post-install step. Is that really necessary? What is the actual goal? Isn't there any other way to "register a widget into a Jupyter notebook"?