# pyproject.toml setuptools: edit user's .bashrc file

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I am writing a Python package that has an entrypoint (cli) script using a pyproject.toml file that builds with setuptools.

I'm installing this package locally with `pip install --user .`
--user is necessary for me because in my environment only my user's dir (/home) is preserved over sessions.

The CLI script gets installed correctly in my /home dir, however the path to it is not added (pip even gives a warning about it).

To solve this problem I would ideally add a line to my `.bashrc` file that appends the CLI script's dir path to PATH.

Is there any way to achieve this through specification in `pip` or `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: No way, and not recommended to pursue. What if a user installs the package into a virtualenv? It shouldn't be added to `$PATH`. What if a user runs `zsh` with its own `.zshrc` and other files? `tcsh`? `fish`? The bottom line: do not mess with user config files.

Comment: @phd you're right there are ways to break my proposed solution. But the problem is that by using `--user` flag with pip the CLI cmds don't get installed to a place on PATH so user cannot use them. Do you have a proposed solution?

Comment: The solution is: document that users should consider updating their `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Python is cross-platform. Python packaging is also cross-platform. What you want to do is not cross-platform (there is no `.bashrc` on Windows), so it is out of scope for Python packaging tools. If it is something that you really want to pursue you will most likely need to resort to using platform specific packaging tools on top of or instead of the Python packaging tools.