# Run a Setup File When the User Installs My Python Package

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have a large code base that contains many plugins. Each plugin has its own docker file. I have written some shell and python files that iterate through the plugin directories and create docker images for each of them.

Now I have to convert this project into a pip installable Python package. The setup scripts must be executed when the user installs the package via the wheel file.

I have tried using the setup.py file. But, it only gets executed once when the package is packed into a wheel file.

Below is my project structure:

```bash
doraemonsay-project$ tree
.
├── doraemonsay
│   ├── doraemon.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── resources
│       └── DORAEMON
├── MANIFEST.in
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.sh

2 directories, 6 files
```

`pyproject.toml`

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "doraemonsay"
version = "1.0.0"

[project.scripts]
doraemonsays = "doraemonsay.__main__:main"

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true
```

`MANIFEST.in`

```
include doraemonsay/resources/*
```

`setup.sh`

```bash
echo "Create docker images..."
```

`doraemonsay/doraemon.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
from sys import path as sys_path
import pkg_resources

resource_path = "resources/DORAEMON"
doraemon_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, resource_path)

def bubble(message):
    bubble_length = len(message) + 3
    return f"""
 {"_" * bubble_length}
( {message} )
 {"‾" * bubble_length}"""

def fetch_message(path):
    """Read text file and return its contents."""
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print(f"cwd: {cwd}")
    print(f"sys_path: {sys_path}")
    with open(path) as f:
        return f.read()

def say(message):
    DORAEMON = fetch_message(doraemon_path)
    message = "Hello Guys, I am doraemon. " +  message
    print(bubble(message))
    print(DORAEMON)
```

`doraemonsay/__main__.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from doraemonsay import doraemon

def say():
    doraemon.say(" ".join(sys.argv[1:]))

def main():
    say()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`doraemonsay/resources/DORAEMON`

```
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⣀⣤⣤⣴⠶⠶⠶⠶⣶⣶⣤⣤⣄⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣠⡤⢴⣿⠿⠯⠤⠤⣤⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣴⠟⠛⠉⠙⠛⢿⣛⠦⣤
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\⠀⣠⡴⠖⠋⢉⡴⠋⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠳⣄⢀⣼⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⢧⡀⠉⠓⢶⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⡴⠚⠉⠀⠀⢠⡟⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⣿⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠨⣷⠀⠀⠀⠈⠛⢦⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣠⡾⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⣀⠀⠀⢿⠀⠀⣀⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⢷⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⡾⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⡟⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⣿⠿⣿⠀⣼⡀⢸⣿⠿⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣧⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⢶⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡼⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⣿⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⢿⡿⠿⠀⣼⣇⠘⢿⡿⠿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⡟⠳⠦⢤⣀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠹⣦⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⢀⡾⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣠⠶⠒⠛⣧⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣿⣿⣹⣦⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣰⠞⠁⠀⠀⠀⠈⠙⠦⣀⠀⠀⠀⠘⢧⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⣾⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡤⠚⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠳⢤⣀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣠⣴⣿⣿⣿⣿⣍⠛⣦⣤⣤⣤⣤⡤⠟⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⣳⣤⠄⠀⠈⣷⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⣸⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⡴⠿⠦⣄⣀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠁⣸⠇⢸⣿⣿⡿⠀⠈⣇ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⡤⠖⠊⠁⠘⣆⠀⠀⠘⣆⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⢀⡏⠀⠀⠀⢠⡞⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠙⠓⠦⣤⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⣧⠀⠈⠉⠀⠀⣴⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣠⡴⠒⠋⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⢧⠀⠀⢿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⣸⠀⠀⠀⢠⠏⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠛⠳⠦⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⠿⢤⣤⣤⠿⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠠⠞⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⣧⠀⢸⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⢠⣿⠀⠀⢀⡎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣾⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⣸⡆⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⢸⡇⠀⠀⣾⠁⡤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠓⠒⠒⠛⠛⠛⠋⠉⠉⢉⡉⠁⠀⠈⣇⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠸⡇⠀⠀⣯⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣼⠃⠀⠀⠀⡿⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⣿⠀⠀⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⣧⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⡀⠀⠀⣰⠃⠀⠀⠀⢀⡇⢀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⢹⠀⠀⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⢷⡀⠀⠀⢀⣀⣀⣀⠤⠤⠶⠓⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠉⠉⣹⠟⠛⠛⠛⠛⢻⠁⢸⠇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠸⡆⠀⢿⡀⠀⢀⣤⣤⠾⢷⣞⠉⠉⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣰⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣾⠀⣼⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠈⣷⠀⠘⡇⠀⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⢷⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢻⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡼⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⡏⢠⡏⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠛⡆⠀⢹⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⣶⣶⣶⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣶⣶⣶⣿⣿⣿⣿⠏⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⡞⢀⡾⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⢻⡀⠀⢳⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠞⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡼⢃⣼⠃⠀⣠⠤⠒⠲⠤⣄⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⢳⡄⠀⢳⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠙⠿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠏⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣼⢃⣾⠃⢀⡞⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠳⣆
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠹⣆⠀⠙⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠛⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⠋⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣼⣧⡞⣀⡟⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⢸
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⢷⣀⠈⢦⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠉⠉⠉⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣼⣷⡿⠾⠋⠉⣇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣴
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⢶⡀⠳⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⣾⡵⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠻⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠞
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣽⢧⣈⡳⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣤⣤⣤⠶⠿⢺⣷⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⢲⡤⣀⣀⡤ ⠚⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢻⣄⡉⠉⠉⠉⠓⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⣲⠶⠶⠶⠶⣖⠚⠛⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠁⠀⢀⣀⣠⠾⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣠⠿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⡞⠉⠉⠛⠓⠲⠤⢤⣤⣄⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⢀⣠⡾       ⣷⣤⣤⡤⢶⡖⠒⠒⠛⠋⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣴⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣠⡟⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣨⠿⠋⠁⠀⠀⠉⠉⢙⣿⠷⠞⠛⠛⠛⠛⠳⠮⣿⠀⠀⠀⠉⠳⡄⠀⠀⠀⠈⣷⠀⠀⠀⢀⣰⠟⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⡟⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡴⠋⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⢧⠀⠀⠀⣼⣷⡶  ⡿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⣦⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⣠⠞⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⡿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡾⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⢧⡀⠀⠀⡟⠀⣠⡞⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⣧⡀⠀⢸⣦⠞⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⣾ ⠀⠀⠀⢰⠀⠀⠀⣾⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠙⠒⠛⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⣇⠀⢸⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⢻ ⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⡟⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢹⠀⢸⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⢾ ⠀⠀⠀⢹⡆⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠰⣶⠶⠶⠶⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠒⠚⠋⠉⠉⣿⠀⠀⢸⠇⢸⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠻⣦⠀⠀⢸⠇⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⠀⠀⡼⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠳⣄⣸⡇⠀ ⢿⡀⠀⠀⢻⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⠇⠀⢰⡇⠀⣾⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⢻⡇⠀⠀⠈⢷⡀⠀⠀⢻⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣰⠏⠀⢀⡟⠀⢠⡟⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⢠⣴⠟⠛⠛⢲⡄⠀⢸⡇⠀⠀⠀⠈⠳⣄⠀⠀⠙⠦⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣤⠞⠃⠀⣠⠟⠀⠀⣸⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⣾ ⣿⠀⠀⠀⣿⠶⢿⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠳⣄⡀⠀⠈⠙⠲⠦⠤⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⣀⡤⠤⠶⠚⠉⠀⠀⣠⠞⠁⠀⠀⢰⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠙⣿⡀⠀⠀⢀⡟⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⠦⣤⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣠⠴⠚⠁⠀⠀⠀⢀⡞⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠙⠛⠛⠉⠀⢀⡏⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠛⠳⠶⠤⠤⢤⡤⠤⠤⠴⠖⠛⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣾⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣠⣴⠿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⣠⣽⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣴⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⠟⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⣶⠞⠉⠉⠁⠈⠙⢦⣤⣀⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⣀⣼⡍⠙⠒⠶⠶⠶⢤⣤⡴⠶⠶⠶⠒⠚⠙⠶⢦⣄⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠁⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⢷⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⢿⡄ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡼⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣻⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠻⣆⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣠⠶⠻⢦⣤⣄⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⣠⡤⠾⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠙⠳⠶⠦⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠶⠶⠚⠛⠋⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠉⠉⠉⠙⠛⠛⠛⠛⠋⠉⠉⠉⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+post-install+script

Comment: You cannot have a post-install code in wheels. You need to convert your `pyproject.toml` to `setup.py` and pack your project to sdist (source distribution in .zip or .tar.gz).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331693/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320274/post-install-script-for-pyproject-toml-projects#comment134583838_76320274