pyproject.toml - autoupdate pip when installing
Whenever I install my projects with pip install -e . they always ends in:
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.2 -> 24.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Is there a way to autoupdate pip?
Tried adding:
dependencies = [
   :
   "pip>=24.3.1",
   :
]

Can I add a post command to just do this?

Not possible. pip/setuptools` don't like scripts and they don't allow post-install scripts. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331693/7976758 and comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75942420/run-post-install-on-pyproject-toml#comment133946910_75942420
